# Max spread of multiple points

Tags: geometry, 2d, coordinates

I have a group of points (x,y) and I need to find out the distance between the two that are farthest apart.

What is the most efficient way to find this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, compairing every point against every other point is certainly **not** efficient.

The most efficient way involves finding the convex hull, which is the convex polygon (no angles > 180) surrounding all points.

After that, you find the farthest points on the hull, using antipodal pairs.

Algorithm described here:

http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/cs153/lectures/module1/module1.html

Comment: This algorithm is called rotating callipers.